# Golang dep doesn't download all library files

Tags: docker, go

I use docker library in my `$GOPATH/src/github.com/docker`
Now I'm trying to use `dep`. In my `gopkg.toml`, it has the following description:

```
[[constraint]]
  name = "github.com/docker/docker"
  version = "1.13.1"
```

But after `dep init` completed, all my codes tell me:

```
Unresolved reference 'NewClientWithOpts'
```

It used to work before I used the `dep`.

```
client.NewClientWithOpts(client.WithVersion("1.38"))
```

---

When I look up my library from vendor, there are 105 files. But from my `src/github.com/docker/client`, It has 212 items!!

---

My questions are:

- Why `dep` did not download all library files?
- How I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have version 1.13.1 as your constraint in the `Gopkg.toml` file, but `NewClientWithOpts()` was introduced after that version. You could either try setting the constraint as `branch = "master"` or `revision = "<latest_commit_sha>"`, or use the v1.13.1 release and look at docs for that specific version.

`dep` doesn't necessarily include all the files from a package - it only keeps sub-packages that are actually being used. That's not a problem in this case though.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `GO111MODULE=on`, the latest docker version is move to `v0.0.0`.

The date of the suffix followed by `v0.0.0` is the relevant docker version number, such as `20190515185722` is the corresponding docker version `19.05`.

So, you can run the command such as:

```sh
go get -v github.com/docker/docker@v0.0.0-0.20190515185722-34b56728ed71
```

You can get the version list by: https://goproxy.io/github.com/docker/docker/@v/